# Why code before break doesn't work?

Tags: c, break

```
int main() {
    int input = 0;
    do {
        if(input > 1) {
            printf("You entered");
            break;
        }

        printf("Enter an integer (> 1): ");
        scanf("%d",&input);

    } while(input < 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Hello, I'm new to C. Could anyone explain what break does? In this program, the statement before break "You entered" doesn't show up on the console. I know java but this works totally different.

Comment: set input to 2, and remove the asterisk before your first printf, then see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for everyone. I didn't notice that mistake I made in the loop. I thought there was something wrong with the break. THANK YOU ALL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no integer exist between `1` and `2`. Change

```
if(input > 1)
```

to

```
if(input > 0)
```

After that if you enter `1` then program enters the `if` body then print `You entered` and on encountering the [`break`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_break_statement.htm) statement, immediately terminates the `do-while` loop.

Comment: You don't really answer anything.

Comment: @ugoren; Yes I did. See `while(input < 2);`.

Comment: He didn't say "please fix my program". He asked what `break` does and what's wrong with his program.

Comment: @ugoren; Yes true. But also see the statement : *In this program, the statement before break "You entered" doesn't show up on the console*.

Comment: @ugoren: what's wrong with his program is that the `printf` statement will never execute because of the logic flaw haccks is pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

The "break" statement causes your code to exit the loop immediately.

You're not seeing any output because you only loop while the input is strictly less than 2, but your if statement is looking for input that's strictly greater than 1.

That's not going to work; if you enter 1, the if statement won't execute (because 1 > 1 is false), and if you enter 2, the loop exits immediately (because 2 < 2 is false).

You either need to loop while input <= 2, or you need to test for input >= 1.

Having said all that...

Standard output is usually *line-buffered*, meaning you won't see anything show up on your console until the buffer is full or you send a newline character.  You either need to manually flush the stream or send a newline as part of the format string; either

```
printf("You entered");
fflush(stdout);
```

or

```
printf("You entered\n");
```

should work.